# How to play the song playing online using c# for Windows phone application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm having the streaming URL(http://stereo.wavestreamer.com:8894). How to play the song in the MediaElement which is playing online in this URL and how to get the artist name?

```
     I tried with the below code on button_click. Its not working.

    private void PlayBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Player.Source = new Uri("http://stereo.wavestreamer.com:8894", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        Player.Volume = 1.0;

        if (Player.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            Player.Play();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: As i am new to this I dont know which is the correct method for streaming using mediaelement.For this, I try to install Naudio, But its not getting installed.(Install-Package NAudio -Version 1.7.1).I'm using visual studio 2013.Can you please explain me in detail.What method to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example about how to stream music from your app on [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Live-Streaming-App-on-59052596/view/Discussions).

You need VS 2012 and the Windows Phone 8 SDK to open it.

You should be able to do it like this:

```
//You have to out your source link here to let the app work , enjoy :)  
Player.Source = new Uri("Your Link goes here", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); 

if (Player.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing) 
{ 
    Player.Play(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I gave the code on button_click. The current state is "Opening" while debugging and the Player.Play() is executing correctly. But the song is not playing. Can you please explain me what's the problem is?